# npm install --save react-compare-image and getting error. unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

PS D:\skinprojecct> npm install --save react-compare-image
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: skinprojecct@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8 || ^17" from react-compare-image@3.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-compare-image
npm ERR!   react-compare-image@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Gourav Srivastava\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gourav Srivastava\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-24T03_44_39_898Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\skinprojecct>

npm install --save react-compare-image

```
Simple React component to compare two images using slider.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you need to resolve deps conflicts
so use any of these :-

```
npm install --save react-compare-image --legacy-peer-deps

npm install --save react-compare-image --force
```